# Play WAV file in Browser from WebAPI

Tags: c#, audio, audio-streaming

I have a challenge. I need to provide an audio to an user to listen it in a web browser.

So, i was trying to begin the solution. What is the best way to provide an audio file (WAV) to an html audio tag play it?

The thing is that when i send it as an url, i believe that the client should need first download all the content, and then start to play. I was thinking something which will run while the data are downloaded, something like a stream.

Do you have an ideia from where to start?

I was thinking something near from Google Drive:

https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={GUIDFromFileFromGoogleDrive}

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is that when i send it as an url, i believe that the client should need first download all the content, and then start to play.

No, this is incorrect.

> I was thinking something which will run while the data are downloaded, something like a stream.

That's how it works.

```
<audio src="https://example.com/your-stream.wav" controls />
```

Comment: @Bisneto I did... the browser doesn't have to download all the content, it will stream it from the server and playback as it goes.

Comment: Ok, now you did. before, no, but thanks for reply. I found the solution, tomorrow I will post it.